# Lifecycle of constructor parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, garbage-collection, lifecycle

I am trying to understand the lifecycle of constructor parameters in Kotlin.
Given the following code, when will `FooFactory` class instance be available for collection by garbage collector?

Since the usage of `FooFactory` is delayed, will the runtime know when to release it?

Or will this create a leak if the compiler does not know when to release `FooFactory` and it will live forever?

```kotlin
class Foo {
    fun doStuff() {}
}

class FooFactory {
    fun getFoo() : Foo {
        return Foo()
    }
}

class User(factory: FooFactory) {
    val x: Foo by lazy {
        factory.getFoo()
    }
}

val user = User(FooFactory())

Thread.sleep(100)

user.x.doStuff()

Thread.sleep(100)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of the `lazy` delegate, which uses `SynchronizedLazyImpl`, you'll see that the initializing lambda is set to null as soon as the value has been computed:

```kotlin
val typedValue = initializer!!()
_value = typedValue
initializer = null
```

So by this line:

```kotlin
user.x.doStuff()
```

`FooFactory` is eligible for garbage collection. However if `x` is never accessed, then `FooFactory` will only be garbage collected once the containing `User` object is garbage collected.

Comment: Seems like this is the case. Thank you!